# CVS checkout aborted..permission denied to rename file

Tags: makefile, cvs

**Hi**
**i have been running a make file to get the source code from the repository but there has been an error in the process it says:**

```
"cvs [checkout aborted]: cannot rename file xxxx.MSBuild.Interop.dll to xxxx.MSBuild.Interop.dll: Permission denied"
```

**i have searched for this problem but i haven't been able to find some good answer or solution of this problem...**

if you have cvs knowledge i ll be grateful if u can help me here.
Thanks

Comment: Are both file names really identical?

Comment: no at xxxx they have different names..

Comment: Oh, then you may have obfuscated details which are required to debug this.

Comment: suppose first file has name _me_build.MSBuild.interop.dll and the file to which i want to rename it is build.MSBuild.interop.dll

Comment: What, very specifically, is the command that is failing? Are you on Windows -
-- could this be a case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: You probably do not have write permission on the target directory, or the destination file exists already and you do not have write permission on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with VirtualBox mount points.
Filesystem vboxsf doesn't allow to checkout with CVS, my error was:

```
cvs [checkout aborted]: cannot rename file .new.FILE1. to FILE1.php: No such file or directory
```

Try to play users groups, permissions and even symbolic link on local VM, no way to get it works. Same thing with permissions on Windows (host) side.

I have to checkout on local directory and then copy to vboxsf mount point, from host or local VM.